# How FB Analytics Capturing Active Users Based on IP or registered user

Tags: facebook-analytics

Do we need to pass the data (like age, gender, country) if yes then how?

or it itself captures all user data?

I have implemented it in web rather than in any app. Provide solution according to it. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to pass anything to view demographics in Facebook Analytics for Apps.  However, you need to have a minimum number of users in a given report view to see demographics.  More information here: 
https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1830887110468299

Comment: Even for the Active users graph, I don't need to pass any information?